# angular-translate: unable to use dynamic data in nested directives

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) package. It provides developers with different things. One thing is internal interpolation so you are able to use dynamic data inside translation strings. Or even angular directives.

Assume we have greeting.

```
'Hello {{name}}!'
```

That is used in template like that:

```
<h3 translate="greeting" translate-values="vm.user" translate-compile></h3>
```

But `user.name` maybe empty. In this case I'd like to see "Hello anonymous!". I'm trying to use `ng-if` but it does not work in expected way:

```
'greeting': 'Hello <span ng-if="!name">anonymous</span>{{name}}!'
```

It will output "Hello anonymousJack!" like if `name` is empty and is not empty at the same time.

Why I don't want to inject `ng-if` into template instead of translation? Because depending on language there will be different position of name part. So I'd like to avoid unclear decomposition like

```
<span translate="greeting_1"></span>
<span ng-if="vm.user.name" bind="vm.user.name"></span>
<span ng-if="!vm.user.name" translate="greeting_anomymous"></span>
<span translate="greeting_2"></span>
```

This looks unclear and confusing. Especially in more complex cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found all data passed through `translate-values` is available in nested variable `interpolateParams`. So next will work:

```
'greeting': 'Hello <span ng-if="!interpolateParams.name">anonymous</span>{{name}}!'
```